# Null Or Multiple Parameters When Querying

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that has a parameter that must take a *comma delimited* varchar list of values that can be turned into a table of values or can be `NULL`, such as

```
@Values VARCHAR(10) = NULL
```

OR

```
@Values VARCHAR(10) = '1,5,10' 

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Parameters') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Parameters
CREATE TABLE #Parameters ( Id INT )

INSERT INTO #Parameters
SELECT
    [Value]
FROM
    FunctionThatReturnsStringToTable(',',@Values)
```

I need to figure out a way to make this work in SQL like so

```
SELECT
   SomeColumns
FROM
   TABLE
WHERE
   COLUMN = IIF(@Values IS NULL, COLUMN, (SELECT Id FROM #Parameters)
```

Which I know will not work. Is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a null parameter this way:

```
WHERE
   @Values IS NULL OR
   COLUMN IN (SELECT Id FROM #Parameters)
```

Comment: PERFECT. I know I was missing something obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table value function which executes quickly instead of temporary tables.  Do not have to test for existence of temporary table and drop it.

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

I choose the XML split function.  Sample calls below.

```
-- A table of items
DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(10) = '1,5,10' 
SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML](@values, ',')

-- Empty Set
DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(10) = NULL 
SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML](@values, ',')
```

Change your code to the following.

```
-- Can be an empty or valued list.
WHERE
    COLUMN IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML](@values, ','))
```

In summary, this assumes your data is XML safe.

Comment: I can't upvote because I just registered for this forum, but thanks for the tip. I've implemented in my query. I love that I don't need to create any temp tables for this.

Comment: Table valued functions (TVF) are the way to go.  Happy TSQL ing!